# typescript fix error argument of type is not assignable

Tags: typescript

I don't know why I'm facing a problem. I have a function that takes an array of objects. Every object has a property named `id` and I wanted to get the last `id` from the given data. The code is working fine.

```
type Data = object;

const data = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Uncategorized',
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'DSLR Cameras',
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'Printer / Ink',
    },
];

const getLastId = (data: Data[]): number => {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
        // Create an array of Id's of all items
        const idsArray: number[] = [];
        data.forEach((obj: { id: number }) => idsArray.push(obj.id));
        // Return last element id
        return idsArray[data.length - 1];
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

But, at the following line, an error is coming.

> data.forEach((obj: { id: number }) => idsArray.push(obj.id));

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(obj: { id: number; }) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: object, index: number, array: object[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'obj' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Property 'id' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ id: number; }'.
```

**What type of error it is and How to fix this?**
[Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UD2AjAVhAxsAbgCgjc0A7AZ2CgBMElUBtIqNqAb1fZ4HIBLWrwBcUAIwAabjza9ycALYQRUXgFVyuBBADmaAE78AXhCFSeAX3PsuM9gKGiATNbtzFy0bxgBlADIASlAAwh76cJS8rlBW0pxxfIIqAMzRfPJKKrwACobkwBD6UAD0UACS5ADWUXGxALrEpBTUUDoQwH4RwGW0KFAAFPSIovCITHUAlKLkAK4KGIUoAHzxPPwAZgMAgvrhIAB0-JQ7e4MME1AAZJd0DPsANhDkOsAAFlArAAwXtnYlpcF9BBtFA4ORQbs4CB0JserxKDDQfd7lB+AUFJQEuwyFQaIJjpCQNM5gt9OM+uNiH9boh9usDABROC4V79fqYLCiDio2jE+aLCwXZArfEnKH7MAzSisjmHWgTCZUv7FUoBdozfTg+5dKAQR5KfI8rFsIHADXg0WEphDOAPJ4vd4AWnEDVquvulGgvzspvN4iVbAsRAsBCAA)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, can you create an online runnable example?

Comment: @KamilNaja [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UD2AjAVhAxsAbgCgjc0A7AZ2CgBMElUBtIqNqAb1fZ4HIBLWrwBcUAIwAabjza9ycALYQRUXgFVyuBBADmaAE78AXhCFSeAX3PsuM9gKGiATNbtzFy0bxgBlADIASlAAwh76cJS8rlBW0pxxfIIqAMzRfPJKKrwACobkwBD6UAD0UACS5ADWUXGxALrEpBTUUDoQwH4RwGW0KFAAFPSIovCITHUAlKLkAK4KGIUoAHzxPPwAZgMAgvrhIAB0-JQ7e4MME1AAZJd0DPsANhDkOsAAFlArAAwXtnYlpcF9BBtFA4ORQbs4CB0JserxKDDQfd7lB+AUFJQEuwyFQaIJjpCQNM5gt9OM+uNiH9boh9usDABROC4V79fqYLCiDio2jE+aLCwXZArfEnKH7MAzSisjmHWgTCZUv7FUoBdozfTg+5dKAQR5KfI8rFsIHADXg0WEphDOAPJ4vd4AWnEDVquvulGgvzspvN4iVbAsRAsBCAA)

Comment: You should pass only obj as a param in forEach call back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Data (I do not like this name) declaration is Object, but should be like this:

```js
type Data = {
    id: number,
    name: string,
};
```

Comment: But now `Data` is static for the specific form of data that has `id` and `name` property. But if I have another form of data that has `id` property but also `address`, `city` and `zipcode` then I have to declare another custom type for that data. I mean that's why I declare a parameter that will take an array of any object.

Comment: if you want only id, you can use: type Data = {
    id: number,
};

Comment: You can add properties to Data by doing Data["adress"]